# ApexChart: Line chart another option

Tags: javascript, apexcharts

Hi I am using АpexChart but I have problem setting up xaxis. The picture below is from another chart, but I'm looking for the effect it has. Note the long straight line, this means there is no data for the specific period.

How do I set up a АpexChart so I can display similar data

```
  var options = {
                series: [{
                        name: "Level",
                        data: [30,45,50,60,70,91,125]
                    }],
                chart: {
                    height: 350,
                    type: 'line',
                    zoom: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                stroke: {
                    curve: 'straight'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Battery',
                    align: 'left'
                },
                grid: {
                    row: {
                        colors: ['#f3f3f3', 'transparent'], // takes an array which will be repeated on columns
                        opacity: 0.5
                    },
                },
                xaxis: {
                    categories: [1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997, 1998,1999]
                }
            };

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart we see on your screenshot has been made with **Highcharts**, right? I know that you can do something similar with **amCharts** or **Chart.js**. But this feature is not available in **ApexCharts** yet. With ApexCharts, you will get blanks (see [demo](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/line-charts/null-values/)) if you have `null` values in your `data`.

Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/747) and this [pull request](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/pull/1788) on GitHub.

Comment of the library author (2019), from the issue:

> This has been proposed, but not worked upon yet.

Comment of the library author (2021), from the PR:

> **Update:** This PR doesn't solve the issue the way we wanted and doesn't cover multiple use-cases.
> Please bear with us. There might be a new PR with a completely different implementation.